# How can I level magic abilities in the game?

Tags: final-fantasy-brave-exvius

There are expeditions that recommend Lvl 5 magic as a prerequisite, and I have people in Friends list with magic (Fira, Cure etc.) that is higher than L1. However, I don't see how magic gains experience (unlike skills, there doesn't seem to be a counter to level it by repeated casting) and there is no option to use Awaken Ability for any of my mages.

How do I level up their magic abilities? Is there a minimum progress needed to unlock this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Levelling up Magic and Skills require "awakening" through items, not XP.

The items you need to level up Magic abilities is called "Crysts". They come in varying sizes, and a certain number of each are required to level up your abilities.

These are called:

- Alcryst
- Milcryst
- Heavicryst
- Giancryst
- Purecryst

These also have varying types, that apply to each "school" of magic. White, Black, Green, as well as varying types for other abilities such as Power, Guard, and Tech, as a few examples.

These items drop from the [Chamber of Gems](https://exvius.gamepedia.com/Chamber_of_Gems), so they can be farmed; all except from the Purecryst varuiants, which only drop from events, or by purchasing them from King Mog.

Not all abilities can be levelled up in this way, some are simply not applicable for this. However, [this list](https://exvius.gamepedia.com/Ability_Awakening) shows all the abilities that *can* be awakened.

Comment: Ugh, Chamber of Gems - I have to level up my units before I re-attempt that; and saving exp boosts till I have a better idea of who is worth it. Good to know it'll be easier to level up skills once I can farm there in a few days!

Comment: Also note that drop rate for Giancryst in the Chamber of Gems is so low you may want to gain them by other sources. A-rank expeditions, King Mog events and story quest events are in my opinion the viable options.